# send bitcoin to mobile number or email address

Tags: blockchain.info, php

How I can send bitcoins to someone's phone number or email address. I explored this [api](https://blockchain.info/api) but they have documentation only for sending bitcoins to an address directly. But [here](https://blog.blockchain.com/2014/08/26/tutorial-how-to-send-bitcoins-using-email-or-sms-messages/) they have explained how to send directly to a mobile number or email address. I want to implement this idea in php, please let me know how I can do it or where I can find some relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: You do not really send the bitcoins to an email-adress or a phone number. You can only transfer them from one bitcoin adress to another one.

My understanding: The internetsite / (software behind it) creates a keypair (private and public key) and generates a bitcoin adress. Then, the site tells the user to send x Btc to that adress and provides you a textfield to enter an email-adress of your fried for example. And after that, the site sends an email to the email adress like "Hey, someone sent you bitcoins. Visit our site http://... 
And finally, you need to provide the 2nd person the opportunity to import the keypair into his wallet or you ask him for a passwort that the first person gave the second person and let him/her enter a new bitcoin adress where he/she than send the bitcoins to. And you should use https for such a project.